# Вопрос по кэшировании хэш-кода string'ом

Tags: java, строки, кэширование

Сегодня встретил следующую фразу

> Класс String - кэширует хэш-код при первом вызове метода `hashCode`

Зачем он его кэширует? Почему при первом вызове? Почему именно хэш-код?

Очевидно предположить что это связано с его `immutable` свойством, но все равно в душе не предполагаю какими есть ответы на эти вопросы( 
Если не сложно поясните пожалуйста кто знает ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вообще говоря, это очень типовая практика в Java кешировать некоторые результаты именно таким образом.

1. Почему при первом вызове?

Потому что до первого вызова `hashcode` может и вовсе не потребуется, соотвественно нет никакого смысла его считать заранее. С другой стороны, если приложение запросило `hashcode`, то нужно вернуть ему корректное значение.

2. Почему именно хэш-код?

Потому что за счет иммутабельности строк хэш-код у строки всегда одинаковый, поэтому никто не мешает его сохранить. К тому же это займет не так много места.

3. Зачем он его кэширует?

Для той же причины, что любое кэширование - для производительности. Вычисление `hashcode` операция довольно затратная (требуется пройти всю строку и вычислить некоторое значение), с другой стороны `hashcode` активно используется при работе с различными коллекциями (set, map и т.д.), соотвественно закешировав это значение можно несколько ускорить работу программы при относительно небольших затратах памяти.

Answer (score 4):

> Зачем он его кэширует?

Затем, чтобы при повторном вызове `hashCode()` не вычислять хэш-код заново.

> Почему при первом вызове?

Потому что до первого вызова метода  `hashCode()` хэш-код еще не рассчитан, а отдать что-то нужно.

> Очевидно предположить что это связано с его immutable свойством

Да, связано. Так как строки неизменяемы, то хэш-код можно закэшировать и не рассчитывать каждый раз заново.